# How to use ng-change in select dropdown with population functionality

Tags: php, angularjs, ng-options

I'm newbie to angular js, I'm building an ionic app in which, I'm trying to populate the select option depends upon first select option, but the variable which is selecting in first select option is not able to process for getting second select option

here is my service.js

```
cityFunction: function(bookUser) {
            var link = 'http://localhost/endpoints/citydetails.php';
            return $http.post(link);
        },
selectedsitesFunction: function(bookUser) {
            var data = { selectedCity1: bookUser.selectedCity1};
            var link = 'http://localhost/endpoints/selectedSites.php';
            return $http.post(link, data);
        }
```

controller.js

```
$scope.bookUser.city = city;            
    $scope.bookUser.selectedCity = "";  
    $scope.bookUser.selectedCity1 = "";
    $scope.bookUser.site1 =[];
    $scope.bookUser.selectedSite1 = "";

$scope.getOptions2 = function(bookUser){
        $scope.bookUser.selectedCity1 = $scope.bookUser.selectedCity.Id;

        AllServices.selectedsitesFunction(bookUser)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };
```

here is html page

```
 <label class="item item-input item-select item-stacked-label">
                                <span class="input-label">City</span>
                                <select name="city" ng-model="bookUser.selectedCity" ng-options="item.City for item in bookUser.city" ng-change="getOptions2(bookUser)">
                                    <option value="">-- select city --</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>

<label class="item item-input item-select item-stacked-label">
                                <span class="input-label">sites</span>
                                <select name="site1" ng-model="bookUser.selectedSite1" ng-options="option for option in bookUser.site1">
                                    <option value="">--select site--</option>
                                </select>
                            </label>
```

and this is .php code

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $selectedCity1 = $data->$selectedCity1;

    $selectedSites = $db->query("SELECT Sites, Id from sitemaster where City = :selectedCity1 ");

    $selectedsites = $selectedSites->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($selectedsites);
?>
```

whenever I'm trying to access this selectedCity1 variable, the console shows the error

`Notice: Undefined variable: selectedCity1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\endpoints\selectedSites.php on line 4`

`Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\endpoints\selectedSites.php on line 4`

Comment: What does this show , if you use print_r($_POST); in your php below json_decode line ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: selectedCity1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\endpoints\selectedSites.php on line 4

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\endpoints\selectedSites.php on line 4..... same error

Comment: did you get anything from my  updated answer ?

Comment: i posted tht error undefined index

Comment: did u check my js code? is it right?

Comment: So I have tried running your code , there are some error except that everything is fine.Is this your whole controller ?

Comment: But i am assure its good on your side, beacuse you are able to make this ajax call .. your error has changed  ..I think now it has something to do with you db query operation

Comment: yes thats my controller code for select option...

Comment: i'm stuck on this since last three days.. please help me sort out this..

Comment: ok , First do this , comment your query's line in php and just echo 1; .. see if it console into response or not .

Comment: output: - {"selectedCity1":1}

Comment: Than there is something wrong in your php

Comment: but what... i cant figure it out.......

Comment: once we get sure we are able to send data from service to php , can you show me what excatly are you sending from controller  to service ?

Comment: i'm sending selected city's id from contrller to service...

Comment: use console.log(bookUser); in your service and send me the output

Comment: Object { advisorid: "A000057", customername: "xyz", bookingdate: "1-10-2016", stime: "02:00 pm", stime1: "14:00:00", etime1: "15:00:00", etime: "03:00 pm", city: Array[4], ttime: undefined, site1: Array[0], 6 more… }

Comment: make sure this object has selectedCity1 parameter in it and try my updated answer in php (y)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$selectedCity1 = $_POST['selectedCity1'];

$query = mysql_query("select Sites, Id from sitemaster where City = "+$selectedCity1+"");
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$output[] = array("site" => $fetch[0],"id" => $fetch[1];
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Hope this helps you :) Thanks

Comment: can you show me output of print_r($_POST) in your php ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: selectedCity1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\endpoints\selectedSites.php on line 15

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\endpoints\selectedSites.php on line 19          getting this error now

Comment: where is your connection.php file ?

Comment: Is it in same folder as given php file ?

Comment: <?php 
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS,DELETE, PUT");if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))  header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:          {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");exit(0);}$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=royaldb;port=3306","root",""););
?>

Comment: did you used ./connection.php?

Comment: created a fiddle .. go for it http://jsfiddle.net/kushcrimson/azu5ajsn/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $selectedCity1 = $data->selectedCity1;

    $selectedSites = $db->query("SELECT Id, Sites FROM sitemaster WHERE City ='$selectedCity1' ");

    $selectedSites = $selectedSites->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($selectedSites);

?>
```

Comment: yup.... but m getting sites in this format ..Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ] like this when i select city, how can i populate this objects in select option list?